# Mi dropdown menú se cierra y no cumple sú función

Tags: javascript, html, scss, dropdown

¡Buenos días! en esta ocasión tengo un **problema lógico** con un dropdown menú que estoy realizando para un proyecto.

### Visualmente... ¿que sucede?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Explicando un poco...

En verdad me está quemando la cabeza ya porque sé que debe ser sencillo arreglarlo... para crear este dropdown menú utilicé HTML, CSS (Sass) y JavaScript. *Estoy seguro que si tuviese conocimientos más amplios de JS no estaría pasando por esto...* XD

Como podrán observar, **el problema es que se ve todo bonito pero de cumplir su función mejor no hablar...** cuando hago :hover sobre el elemento li 'Edición de video' despliega el menú pero al salirme de su padding me cierra el menú.

### ¿Qué deseo?

Busco que mi dropdown-menu no se esfume tras salir del padding del li, si no que desaparezca cuando el ratón salga del width o el height del mismo drop-down

### Código

#### HTML

```
<header class="encabezado">
    <div class="desktop-version">
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/logos/dvz-color.png" alt="dvz-logo"></a>
            </div>
            <!-- Ícono Open Menú Responsive -->
            <div class="toggle-menu" id="toggle">
                <i class='bx bx-grid-alt'></i>
            </div>
            <!-- Secciones del Navbar -->
            <ul class="nav-list" id="nav-mobile">
                <!-- Ícono Close Menu -->
                <div class="close-menu" id="close-menu">
                    <i class='bx bx-x' ></i>
                </div>

                <!-- Edicion de video (dropdown)-->
                <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-link">Edición de video <i class='bx bx-chevron-down dropdown-icon'></i></a></li>
                <div class="mega-menu">
                    <ul class="content">
                        <li class="mega-menu_item header-megamenu">Softwares</li>
                        <li class="mega-menu_item">
                            <div class="megamenu-icon">
                                <img src="assets/iconos/after-effects.png" alt="after-effects">
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu-link_div">
                                <a href="#" class="menu-link">Adobe After Effects</a>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt, ex.</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li class="mega-menu_item">
                            <div class="megamenu-icon">
                                <img src="assets/iconos/premiere.png" alt="premiere">
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu-link_div">
                                <a href="#" class="menu-link">Adobe Premiere Pro</a>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium, quas.</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li class="mega-menu_item">
                            <div class="megamenu-icon">
                                <img src="assets/iconos/davinci-resolve.png" alt="davinci-resolve">
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu-link_div">
                                <a href="#" class="menu-link">Da Vinci Resolve</a>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur, dolorum?</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li class="mega-menu_item">
                            <div class="megamenu-icon">
                                <img src="assets/iconos/filmora.png" alt="filmora" class="filmora">
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu-link_div">
                                <a href="#" class="menu-link">Wondershare Filmora</a>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur, dolorum?</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Otras secciones -->
                <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-link">Edición de audio <i class='bx bx-chevron-down dropdown-icon'></i></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-link">Diseño Gráfico <i class='bx bx-chevron-down dropdown-icon'></i></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-link">Desarrollo Web <i class='bx bx-chevron-down dropdown-icon'></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    </header>
```

#### CSS (SASS)

```
.encabezado {
    grid-area: header;

    .desktop-version {
        nav {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
            z-index: 999;
            font-size: 1.7rem;
            padding: 0px 40px;

            .logo {
                img {
                    height: 80px;
                }
            }

            .toggle-menu {
                display: none;

                @include mQuerie(m) {
                    display: block;
                    cursor: pointer;

                    i {
                        font-size: 4rem;
                        color: #000;

                        &:hover {
                            transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
                            color: $principal;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            .nav-list {
                display: flex;

                @include mQuerie(m) {
                    position: absolute;
                    height: 100vh;
                    width: 100%;
                    left: -100%;
                    max-width: 350px;
                    top: 0;
                    background-color: #fff;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    margin: 0;
                    overflow-x: hidden;
                    display: block;
                    transition: .3s;
                }

                .close-menu {
                    display: none;

                    @include mQuerie(m) {
                        display: block;
                        margin: 10px 10px 10px auto;
                        background-color: $secundario;
                        border-radius: 50%;
                        height: 32px;
                        width: 32px;
                        text-align: center;
                        cursor: pointer;

                        i {
                            line-height: 32px;
                            color: #fff;
                            font-size: 22px;
                        }
                    }
                }

                .mega-menu {
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 100%;
                    top: 8rem;
                    left: 0;
                    background-color: #fff;
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;
                    flex-direction: row;
                    border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
                    box-shadow: 0 23px 23px -21px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
                    z-index: 99;
                    visibility: hidden;
                    opacity: 0;

                    @include mQuerie(m) {
                        justify-content: flex-start;
                        flex-wrap: wrap;
                        flex-direction: column;
                        position: static;
                        box-shadow: none;
                        border-radius: 0;
                        height: 0;
                        max-width: 350px;
                        overflow: hidden;
                    }

                    .content {
                        display: flex;
                        flex-direction: column;
                        padding: 1rem;

                        .mega-menu_item {
                            display: flex;
                            align-items: center;
                            margin-bottom: 1rem;

                            .megamenu-icon {
                                height: 34px;
                                width: 34px;
                                border-radius: 50%;
                                text-align: center;
                                background-color: #efeef1;
                                margin-right: 0.8rem;
                                margin-bottom: 1rem;

                                .filmora {
                                    border-radius: 50%;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        .header-megamenu {
                            font-weight: bolder;
                            margin-bottom: 1rem;
                        }

                        .menu-link_div {
                            .menu-link {
                                font-weight: bold;
                                color: black;

                                &:hover {
                                    color: $principal;
                                }
                            }

                            p {
                                color: #a8a1b5;
                                font-size: 1.2rem;
                                font-weight: 400;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                /// Aca hay problema ///
                .dropdown:hover + .mega-menu {
                    transition: all .3 ease;
                    visibility: visible;
                    opacity: 1;

                    @include mQuerie(m) {
                        height: 40%;
                        -moz-height: 35%;
                    }
                }

                .nav-item {
                    list-style: none;
                    margin: 0 15px;
                    padding: 14px 0;

                    .nav-link {
                        text-decoration: none;
                        color: black;
                        font-weight: bolder;

                        &:hover {
                            color: $principal;
                        }
                    }

                    .dropdown-link {
                        display: flex;
                        align-items: center;
                    }
                }

                .nav-item:hover .dropdown-icon {
                    transform: rotate(180deg);
                    transition: all .3s ease;
                }
            }

            .show_menu {
                left: 0;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

#### JavaScript

```
const navMenu = document.getElementById('nav-mobile'),
    openMenu = document.getElementById('toggle'),
    closeMenu = document.getElementById('close-menu');

openMenu.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navMenu.classList.toggle('show_menu')
}
)

closeMenu.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navMenu.classList.remove('show_menu')
})
```

#### Código adicional por las moscas... (GRID LAYOUT)

```
.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 150px;
    grid-template-areas:    "header"
                            "main"
                            "footer";
}
```

Comment: No puedo probar para darte una respuesta certera, pero entiendo que el `:hover` se ejecuta sobre esto `<li class="nav-item dropdown"><a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-link">Edición de video <iclass='bx bx-chevron-down dropdown-icon'></i></a></li>` El codigo que viene por debajo no son etiquetas `child` de ese `<li>` por lo que no van a heredar el CSS de la misma. Intenta crear un `<div>` que contenga todo y crea el `:hover` sobre dicho `<div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola cómo estás?? Creo que la siguiente solución te podría ayudar

**Paso 1:** quita el visibility: hidden; y opacity: 0; de la clase *.mega-menu*

**Paso 2:** Colócale display: none; a la clase *.mega-menu* y agregale un ***top*** del tamaño de la altura de la etiqueta ***a*** ,por ejemplo, top: 62px;

**Paso 3:** En el HTML pone el ***div*** con la clase *.mega-menu* dentro del elemento ***li***, como se muestra a continuación:

```html
<li class="nav-item dropdown"><a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-link">Edición de video <i
                                class='bx bx-chevron-down dropdown-icon'></i></a>
                        <div class="mega-menu">
                            <ul class="content">
                                <li class="mega-menu_item header-megamenu">Softwares</li>
                                <li class="mega-menu_item">
                                    <div class="megamenu-icon">
                                        <img src="assets/iconos/after-effects.png" alt="after-effects">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menu-link_div">
                                        <a href="#" class="menu-link">Adobe After Effects</a>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt, ex.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="mega-menu_item">
                                    <div class="megamenu-icon">
                                        <img src="assets/iconos/premiere.png" alt="premiere">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menu-link_div">
                                        <a href="#" class="menu-link">Adobe Premiere Pro</a>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium, quas.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="mega-menu_item">
                                    <div class="megamenu-icon">
                                        <img src="assets/iconos/davinci-resolve.png" alt="davinci-resolve">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menu-link_div">
                                        <a href="#" class="menu-link">Da Vinci Resolve</a>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur, dolorum?
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="mega-menu_item">
                                    <div class="megamenu-icon">
                                        <img src="assets/iconos/filmora.png" alt="filmora" class="filmora">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menu-link_div">
                                        <a href="#" class="menu-link">Wondershare Filmora</a>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur, dolorum?
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
```

**Paso 4:** Ponele un position: relative; a la clase .dropdown

**Paso 5:** En tu HTML colócale un *id=”main”* al elemento main y si no tienes la etiqueta ***main*** colocala envolviendo al código pincipal, como se explica a continuación: [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main)

**Paso 6:** Copia el siguiente código de javascript:

```js
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown')
const megaMenu = document.querySelector('.mega-menu')
const main = document.getElementById('main')

function menu (){
    dropdown.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) =>{
        megaMenu.style.display = 'flex'
    })
    main.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) =>{
        megaMenu.style.display = 'none'
    })
}

window.addEventListener('mouseover', menu)
```

Espero que te sirva mi aporte :)

Comment: La respuesta de Franco me sirvió! ahora solo queda hacerlo funcionar con la Media Query (: gracias♥

Comment: De nada Tomás, me alegra que te sirviera